# Is there a term for the relationship of vector subspaces $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Would it be correct to say $U_1$ and $U_2$ "intersect trivially"? Is there an established term?

Comment: Just call them *disjoint*.

Comment: Aren't two sets disjoint when they have no element in common?

Comment: In French we would say that *$U_1$ and $U_2$ sont en somme directe*. While the notion of [Direct sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) exists in English, I’m not sure it can be applied for linear subspaces. Does someone has a clue on the question?

Comment: @B.Swan: yes, you are right but in the context of subspaces this can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Subspaces with trivial intersection" or "subspaces that intersect trivially" sounds ok to me, especially for speaking. But I usually write "$U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$".

The condition makes the sum $U_1+U_2$ a direct sum.